# Determine if $-2x-4x^2+12y = 4y^2 -1$ represents a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

I was given the following question on a practice test:

> Determine whether the following equation represents a circle. If so, find its centre and radius. If not, list all reasons why.
>   $$-2x-4x^2+12y = 4y^2 -1$$

The instructor posted the solution

> $$h=-\frac14 \qquad k=\frac32 \qquad r=\sqrt{\frac{41}{16}}=\frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}$$

But didn't give details on how to solve it.

It would be great if someone could explain to me the steps of the solution, as I'm having trouble getting it into the form of a circle equation.

Comment: A circle with center $(x_0,y_0)$ and radius $r$ is of the form $(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2=r^2$.  Try to get your equation to fit that form.

Comment: In keeping with @JMoravitz hint, please realize you will want to complete the squares in order to find $(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = r^2$.  I take it that your h, k, respectively represent $x_0, y_0$.

Comment: First, if the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are not the same, you will not have a circle.  Then, complete the square twice.

Comment: Wow, if not, list *all* reasons why?  Taken literally, that would be impossible to do in a finite amount of paper (assuming that means all proofs it's not a circle, including proofs that take unnecessary diversions).  `\end{tongueincheek}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearranging some things:

$4x^2+2x + 4y^2-12y = 1$

Dividing by $4$ and adding $\square$'s as placeholders for values that we want to see in the future to "complete the square" so that we can more conveniently represent things.

$x^2+\frac{1}{2}x+\color{blue}\square + y^2-3y+\color{red}\square = \frac{1}{4}+\color{blue}\square+\color{red}\square$

Now, we want to pick a value for $\color{blue}\square$ such that the first three terms wind up in the form $(x+a)^2=x^2+2ax+a^2$.

Well, if since the $x$ term that we do already have is $\frac{1}{2}$ and since we want it to look like $2ax$, by setting them equal $2ax = \frac{1}{2}x$, and then dividing both sides by $2x$ we get $a=\frac{1}{4}$, so we will use a value of $a^2=(\frac{1}{4})^2=\frac{1}{16}$ in place of our $\color{blue}\square$.  In doing so, we  have:

$x^2+2\cdot \frac{1}{4}x + (\frac{1}{4})^2 + y^2-3y+\color{red}\square=\frac{1}{4}+(\frac{1}{4})^2+\color{red}\square$

Factoring the quadratic in $x$

$(x+\frac{1}{4})^2 + y^2-3y+\color{red}\square = \frac{1}{4}+(\frac{1}{4})^2+\color{red}\square$

And writing the quadratic in $x$ with a minus instead so that it is in the desired form

$(x-(-\frac{1}{4}))^2 + y^2-3y+\color{red}\square = \frac{1}{4}+(\frac{1}{4})^2+\color{red}\square$

---

I leave completing the square for $y$ to you now that you have seen how it was performed for $x$.

You will wind up learning that this *is* going to be a circle, and it will be centered around the point $(-\frac{1}{4},y_0)$ with radius $\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+(\frac{1}{4})^2+\color{red}\square}$ where I leave calculating $y_0$ and $\color{red}\square$ to you to finish.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation cleared things up so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use unknown coefficients method as follows:

Suppose equation of circle is:

$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$

$x^2-2ax+a^2+y^2-2by+b^2=r^2$

Now we rewrite equation and compare the coefficient of powers of x and y and constant of two equation :

$x^2+\frac{1}{2}x+y^2-3y=\frac{1}{4}$

So we must have:

$-2a=\frac{1}{2}$ ⇒ $a=-\frac{1}{4}$

$-2b=-3$ ⇒ $b=\frac{3}{2}$

$r^2-a^2-b^2=\frac{1}{4}$ ⇒$r^2=(-\frac{1}{4})^2+(\frac{3}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{41}{16}$

⇒ $r=\frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}$